# Windows can't find localstack

Tags: python, pip

I have some trouble to start and run localstack. I can install localstack relatively easy with "pip install localstack". This worked for me without problems. After the installation I tried to start localstack with "localstack start" but then windows tells me it can't find localstack.

> The command "localstack" is either misspelled or could not be found.

I searched a lot and found out there are some similar problems. In one issue I found something that could eventually work for me. In this question. Because I never worked with python this is a little bit confusing for me. I tried this answer. I switched into the python scripts folder and run the command "py localstack start". Here it is interesting, that I get an error again, but this time windows recognizes localstack.

This here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "localstack", line 31, in <module>
    from localstack.utils import cli
  File "c:\users\gion rubitschung\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\localstack\utils\cli.py", line 4, in <module>
    from localstack.services import infra
  File "c:\users\gion rubitschung\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\localstack\services\infra.py", line 20, in <module>
    from localstack.utils import common, persistence
  File "c:\users\gion rubitschung\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\localstack\utils\common.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pty
  File "c:\users\gion rubitschung\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\pty.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tty
  File "c:\users\gion rubitschung\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\tty.py", line 5, in <module>
    from termios import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'
```

How can I start localstack just by typing "localstack start"?

Comment: try installing `termios`...

Comment: Termios is not a python package. This is a [linux only feature](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/termios.html). Not supported on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Install the `0.9.0` version** with:

`python -m pip install localstack==0.9.0`

(First you have to uninstall the latest one.)

From [localstack's issues](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/563).

Answer (score 0):

You can install it directly from the [Commandeer App](https://getcommandeer.com). It uses docker under the hood.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to install Localstack on Windows is by using Docker. Here are the steps:

1. Install Docker. Instructions given in the post below:
   https://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_1.html
2. Pull the latest LocalStack Docker Image using the command below:

   $ docker pull localstack/localstack
3. Start LocalStack using the command below:

   $ docker run --rm -p 4566:4566 -p 4571:4571 localstack/localstack

All these instructions are mentioned in the blog post below:
https://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/p/how-to-install-localstack-on-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

0

I added the path but still the problem persisted. So I started afresh. (I am on Windows 10)

Following is what I did

1. Downloaded the respective binary for my architecture directly from https://docs.localstack.cloud/getting-started/installation/
2. Extracted the file
3. After extraction, moved to the directory. The problem is, If I just run **localstack --version** from the directory, I got an error saying "*localstack : The term 'localstack' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.*"

this was because localstack command is not found in my system's PATH, and I was running it from a directory where it is not recognized as an executable.

So instead , I ran the command **.\localstack --version** and this worked!

Then I started it with **.\localstack start**

I am not sure how much this will help you.

I am just a beginner and sharing whatever has helped me to go around the problem.

#pip #localstackinstallation #localstack

Comment: Hi? Since this was resolved a while ago, maybe please elaborate on how your answer complements or updates the accepted answer. If your problem was similar but significantly different, though, it might be more useful to open a new post of your own.

Comment: Hi, this question is quite old and has been solved at the time. As of now I am using docker for localstack. Maybe looking into docker will help you aswell, because you can quite easily install different stuff with it (for example dbs etc)